# How does Serilog calculate Elapsed in Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, serilog

For Web API in .NET 6, I'm configuring `Serilog` request logging.

```
app.UseSerilogRequestLogging(options =>
{
    options.MessageTemplate = "Elapsed: {Elapsed:0.0000} ms";
});
```

How is `Elapsed` calculated exactly?

Comment: It's open source. You can find the source code on GitHub and look through it if you wish. There's not much to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serilog has custom [`RequestLoggingMiddleware`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/blob/dev/src/Serilog.AspNetCore/AspNetCore/RequestLoggingMiddleware.cs) which is injected into pipeline via `UseSerilogRequestLogging` call (that's why it is important to call this method as early as possible because otherwise it will not take into account time consumed by components that appear before it in the pipeline, as [mentioned in the docs](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore#request-logging)).

The implementation is pretty straightforward - sample time at the start of logging middleware, invoke the rest of pipeline, sample time at the end, calculate the difference. Currently calculation [looks somewhat like this](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/blob/bf4ae072f7472d285c72f9a43f3eb4920e743110/src/Serilog.AspNetCore/AspNetCore/RequestLoggingMiddleware.cs#L56):

```cs
var start = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

var Elapsed = GetElapsedMilliseconds(start, Stopwatch.GetTimestamp());

static double GetElapsedMilliseconds(long start, long stop)
{
    return (stop - start) * 1000 / (double)Stopwatch.Frequency;
}
```